# Cannot make a regexp work with integer numbers

Tags: c#, regex

The following regexp works well with float numbers:

```
Regex.Match("fdsfds 2.2 fdsfd", @"((\d)+.(\d)+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value
```

I can't get it to work with integer numbers. So I'll be able to parse both integer and float numbers.

Any help?

Comment: Your regex fails for negative numbers.

Comment: the unescaped `.` would cause 1x2 to match

Comment: IgnoreCase for numbers?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Regex should make the decimal-separator and the decimals optional.
Try something like this:

```
@"(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)"
```

Comment: The dot should be escaped. It was when I wrote the answer, and when I try to edit my answer, but ends up unescaped here somehow.

Comment: I think it's traditional to allow a "+" sign too.